# MyBatis: Error when adding a 'bind' inside of 'foreach'

Tags: mybatis, dtd

I'm using MyBatis for handling SQL queries. Here is my problematic piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.foo.Foo">
    ...
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="com.foo.FooParam">
        <foreach collection="bars" item="bar" separator=" ">
            <bind name="inFavorites" value="bar.sectionId == '_favorites'" />
            <foreach collection="bar.bars2" item="bar2" index="index" separator=" ">
               ...
            </foreach>
        </foreach>
     </insert>
    ...
</mapper>
```

Intelij shows the following error when validiting the xml:

> Error:(24, 74) Element type "bind" must be declared.
>
> Error:(28, 19) The content of element type "foreach" must match "(include|trim|where|set|foreach|choose|if)".

And when i put a compiled module as an osgi package in a jetty server (mvn compiles it w/o errors and warnings) I'm getting the following error:

> lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 19; The content of element type "foreach"
>   must match "(include|trim|where|set|foreach|choose|if)".

So Ok, I get this. I cannot add a 'bind' element inside of a 'foreach'.

But why, if http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd says otherwise?

```
<!ELEMENT foreach (#PCDATA | include | trim | where | set | foreach | choose | if | bind)*>
```

Answer (score 1):

`bind` inside `foreach` is allowed since [version 3.2.3](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/commit/0b6a04d9a7586f994b635f96c91cdfc5bff1f462#diff-b844a0ed11523635f2a371336a1d7362). You are obviously using an older version.

dtd file is not downloaded from the internet but the version packaged in mybatis jar is used.